# Derivation of a log of an integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I've come across the following derivation

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}  \log_2 \left(\int p(x)^\alpha \, \mathrm{d}x \right)
$$

but cannot figure out, what tricks are required to solve it nicely. Definitely some chain rule but the log of the integral looks scary.

($p(x)$ is probability density; an alternative version with probability mass function, with sum instead of integral, was easy)

Comment: Hint: $\frac{d}{dx}\log_{b}(f(x)) = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\ln(f(x))}{\ln(b)} = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)\ln(b)}$

Comment: May be [this](http://fy.chalmers.se/~tfkhj/FeynmanIntegration.pdf) is helpful too, since you might want to differentiate under the integral

Comment: "INTEGRATION: THE FEYNMAN WAY" looks very relevant, in particular Theorem 2.1. Thank you, @PeterMelech! The change of log base is clear, thanks @Joshua Wang.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\partial \log _2\left(\int p(x)^{\alpha } \, dx\right)}{\partial \alpha }=\frac{\partial \frac{\log \left(\int p(x)^{\alpha } \, dx\right)}{\log 2}}{\partial \alpha }=\frac{1}{\log 2}\frac{\partial \log \left(\int p(x)^{\alpha } \, dx\right)}{\partial \alpha }=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\log 2}\frac{\int p(x)^{\alpha } \log (p(x)) \, dx}{\int p(x)^{\alpha } \, dx}$$

---

Example

$$\log _2\left(\int x^{\alpha } \, dx\right)=\frac{\log \left(\frac{x^{\alpha +1}}{\alpha +1}\right)}{\log 2}+C$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\log _2\left(\int x^{\alpha } \, dx\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\frac{\log \left(\frac{x^{\alpha +1}}{\alpha +1}\right)}{\log 2}=\frac{1}{\log 2}\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\left((\alpha+1)\log x-\log(\alpha+1)\right)=\frac{1}{\log 2}\left(\log x-\frac{1}{\alpha+1}\right)$$

Using the formula above

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\log _2\left(\int x^{\alpha } \, dx\right)=\frac{1}{\log 2}\frac{\int \left(x^{\alpha}\log x\right)\,dx}{\int x^{\alpha}\,dx}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\log 2}\frac{\frac{x^{\alpha +1} ((\alpha +1) \log x-1)}{(\alpha +1)^2}}{\frac{x^{\alpha +1}}{\alpha +1}}=\frac{1}{\log 2}\frac{x^{\alpha +1} ((\alpha +1) \log x-1)}{(\alpha +1)^2}\cdot \frac{\alpha +1}{x^{\alpha +1}}=\frac{1}{\log 2}\frac{(\alpha +1) \log (x)-1}{\alpha +1}$$

Comment: Thank you, thought I still do not see the trick to get from $\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \log (\int p(x)^\alpha dx)$ to the next step right above. Changing the base of logarithm is clear, but that's not the issue.

Comment: I think in line 2 a factor $\frac{1}{\log 2}$ is missing. The rest is an application of the chain rule and then Raffaele differentiates under the integral, using $\frac{\partial p(x)^{\alpha}}{\partial \alpha}=p(x)^{\alpha}\log (p(x))$. However this needs some justification

Comment: I see - so that's the trick - differentiation under the integral sign. However, Wikipedia shows it only for definitie integrals, while here we have an indefinite one. How do we know we can use this trick?